# Appengine module: Routing with dispatch.yaml not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using modules, but i cannot put to work the routing as explanined here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing

to update:

```
appcfg.py update dispatch.yaml app.yaml comunapp_site.yaml

appcfg.py update_dispatch
```

the endpoint api works as expected but the site doesn't
i expected this to work

```
https://skilled-cargo-111.appspot.com/comunapp/
```

but only this works

```
https://comunapp-dot-skilled-cargo-111.appspot.com/
```

Here are my yaml file:

app.yaml

```
application: skilled-cargo-111
module: default
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes    

automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
  max_pending_latency: 3s    

handlers:
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: mobile_api.application   

libraries:
- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
```

comunapp_site.yaml

```
application: skilled-cargo-111
module: comunapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
  max_pending_latency: 10s

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /bootstrap
  static_dir: bootstrap

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /javascript
  static_dir: javascript


#- url: /login.*
#  script: "main.py"
#  secure: always

- url: /.*
  script: comunapp_site.app
  login: optional
  secure: always

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

dispatch.yaml

```
application: skilled-cargo-111

dispatch:
  - url: "*/favicon.ico"
    module: default

  - url: "*/comunapp/*"
    module: comunapp

  - url: "*/api/*"
    module: default
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's happening is that your dispatch file says to route any request coming to *hostname/comunapp/** to your **comunapp** handler, but the URL getting to that handler is of the type *skilled-cargo-111.appspot.com/comunapp/*, while you probably only set up the handler for the **/** path, as you did with the default module.

If you're using Python, try updating your code to something like:

```
comunapp = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/comunapp/*', ComunApp),
], debug=True)
```

It should do the trick.

Also for the "api" path, you should add the "/api/" handler in the default module code.

You could check if dispatch file is working correctly by checking the logs for the comunapp module in the Developers' Console. If you see the requests for /comunapp/* URLs but get a 404 error is what I mentioned earlier. If you wouldn't see anything of those URLs appearing in the comunapp module logs, then the dispatch file is the key to solve the issue.

Comment: Yep that's the solution. Thank you very much

Comment: I've got the exact same problem, except I'm using a Flask application (app defined with `comunapp = flask.Flask('application')`, routes defined with `comunapp.add_url_rule('/comunapp/foo', view_func=foo)`. Any idea how to translate this solution to my use case?

Comment: Figured out the answer: I had the entries in dispatch.yaml reversed. Turns out that rule order matters.

Comment: Seems so simple in retrospect, but this didn't even occur to me. Thank you!