# Module does not work in gae with django framework

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I am using google app engine with the django framework.

I have two modules: default and helloworld

the app.yaml is as follows:

```
application: myapp
version: release
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/favicon.ico
  upload: static/favicon.ico
- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: static/robots.txt
  upload: static/robots.txt
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred.application
  login: admin
- url: /.*
  script: myapp.wsgi.application
  secure: always
```

I want all the `myapp.appspot.com/helloworld/*` will be routed to the helloworld module.

The dispatch.yaml is as follows:

```
application: myapp
dispatch:
- url: "*/helloworld/*"
  module: helloworld
```

here is helloworld.yaml:

```
application: myapp
module: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
instance_class: B2
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 3

handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/favicon.ico
  upload: static/favicon.ico
- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: static/robots.txt
  upload: static/robots.txt
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred.application
  login: admin
- url: /.*
  script: myapp.wsgi.application
  secure: always
```

However, when the coming url is `myapp.appspot.com/helloworld/*`, the page will be redirected to the login page. and the log shows `/_ah/start` 404.

I have seen the similar question in [Appengine module: Routing with dispatch.yaml not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978198/appengine-module-routing-with-dispatch-yaml-not-working) which modifies wsgi config with webapp2 framework.

Here is my wsgi.py

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir, 'libs'))

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I use `appcfg update app.yaml helloworld.yaml` and `appcfg update_dispatch .` to upload these settings.

How can I import this helloworld module correctly with the django framework?

Thank you.

Comment: Post the contents of your `dispatch.yaml`

Comment: Does your `helloworld` module have a handler that matches `helloworld/*`?

Comment: No, actually, I do not understand how the handler in the module work if the coming url is routing by dispatcher.

Comment: Pretend that it is a stand alone application. It needs a view registered to match `/helloworld/` in order to respond to that request. If not you get a 404.

Comment: /helloworld/ is in myapp.url and it will be routed to helloworld.url. helloworld is not only a module but also an app in my django-based project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92507/discussion-between-user3378223-and-josh-trii-johnston).